# Extract a string in batch based on string matching (remove the matched string)

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a string

```
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 133ms, Maximum = 150ms, Average = 142ms
```

And a for loop

```
for /l %%x in (1, 1, 10) do (
    for /f "tokens=7,9" %%a in ('ping -n 10 !ipaddr!') do (
        if "x%%a"=="xAverage" (
```

If the 7th token (`%a`) is "Average" then I want to check `if /I %%b GTR 300`. But for that I need to get rid of the `ms` in `142ms` (`%b`). What should I do?

Answer (score 3):

Use delayed expansion with

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
```

and assign to a temporary variable within the loop:

```
set avg=%%b
set avg=!avg:ms=!
```

and then use `!avg!`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do nothing (just eliminate the /I switch in IF command). Because numbers are also strings, you can directly do the desired comparison and get the correct result:

```
if 142ms GTR 300 echo This not appear: 142ms is less than 300
if 350ms GTR 300 echo This appear: 350ms is greater than 300
```

The only problem happen when Average is precisely 300ms, but this case can be easily solved changing the value to 301:

```
if 300ms gtr 300 echo This appear but is wrong: 300ms is equal 300, not greater 
if %%b gtr 301 echo OK: This appear when the value is greater 300 in all cases
```

Antonio